# I manage to call just one array item ,but my code needs to call all array items

Tags: php

When i call the function it only shows just the first item from the array

This is my array:

```
$produse = array(
1=> array(
    'id'    =>  1,
    'nume'  => 'produs 1',
    'pret'  =>  35.99,
    'cant'  =>  10
    ),
3=> array(
    'id'    =>  3,
    'nume'  =>  'LCD SAMSUNG',
    'pret'  =>  89.99,
    'cant'  =>  15
    ),
4=> array(
    'id'    =>  4,
    'nume'  =>  'baterie alcatel',
    'pret'  =>  9.99,
    'cant'  =>  20
    ),
5=> array(
    'id'    =>  5,
    'nume'  =>  'baterie asus',
    'pret'  =>  14.99,
    'cant'  =>  25
    ),
);
```

This is the my function to call the array with the full price of the items

```
function total() {          
     global $produse;
     foreach ($produse as $key=>$row) {
         $pret_item = $row["pret"]*$row["cant"];
         $all_items = '   <Row ss:Height="15.75">
              <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">'.$row['id'].'</Data></Cell>
              <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.$row['nume'].'</Data></Cell>
              <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">'.$row['pret'].'</Data></Cell>
              <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">'.$row['cant'].'</Data></Cell>
              <Cell ss:Formula="=RC[-1]*RC[-2]"><Data ss:Type="Number">'.$pret_item.'</Data></Cell>
              </Row>';
         return $all_items;
    }
}
```

When i call the function i get just the first item and not the others as well:

```
<Row ss:Height="15.75">
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">produs 1</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">35.99</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">10</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:Formula="=RC[-1]*RC[-2]"><Data ss:Type="Number">359.9</Data></Cell>
```

Comment: globals inside functions tend to never be the answer - pass it as a parameter instead

Comment: You calling your `return` inside of the `foreach` loop, that's why you only get one item. `return` will end the loop and return the current value of the variable. Make  `$all_items` an array or concatenated string instead and return outside the loop

Comment: Do you want to return array of string or concatenated string?

Comment: @treyBake how do i pass it as a parameter ?

Comment: `function foo($total) {}` then `$foo = foo(54)` (for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append in your foreach like this,

```
$all_items = "";
foreach ($produse as $key=>$row) {
    $pret_item = $row["pret"] * $row["cant"];
    $all_items .= '   <Row ss:Height="15.75">
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">' . $row['id'] . '</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">' . $row['nume'] . '</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">' . $row['pret'] . '</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">' . $row['cant'] . '</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:Formula="=RC[-1]*RC[-2]"><Data ss:Type="Number">' . $pret_item . '</Data></Cell>
       </Row>';
}
return $all_items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
function total() {
        global $produse;
        $all_items = '';
        foreach ($produse as $key=>$row) {

            $pret_item = $row["pret"]*$row["cant"];
            $all_items .= '<Row ss:Height="15.75">
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">'.$row['id'].'</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.$row['nume'].'</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">'.$row['pret'].'</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">'.$row['cant'].'</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:Formula="=RC[-1]*RC[-2]"><Data ss:Type="Number">'.$pret_item.'</Data></Cell>
                </Row>';

        }
        return $all_items;
    }
```